# Assume class template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I have a Kd-Tree implementation, which is templatized to accept any dimension greater than 0 and any floating-point type (float, double, etc...). Something like this:

```
template <typename real, size_t dimensions> class KdTree
{
    // stuff
}
```

And I have an accompanying "point" type which has the exact same template layout. However this point type *needs to be accessible from outside the kd-tree class*. Now, every time I need to create temporary points inside my kd-tree code, I need to explicitly go `KdPoint<real, dimensions>`, which is tiresome, makes my lines really long, and adds no value whatsoever to the code.

Is there any way I can tell the compiler to implicitly assume whatever values for `real` and `dimensions` were passed to the class for the points as well? Linking the two template lists together, in a way. So that I can just type `KdPoint` and the compiler will directly know what to put in there, based on the template arguments the class received.

Otherwise I'll need to use a macro to explicitly expand the latter into the former, which kind of sucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a typedef to the `KdTree` class:

```
template <typename real, size_t dimensions> class KdTree
{
  typedef KdPoint<real, dimensions> KdPoint_;
  // stuff
};
```

and use `KdPoint_` internally. If you want the point type to be accessible externally, give the `typedef` public access, and a name that doesn-t end in `_`:

```
template <typename real, size_t dimensions> class KdTree
{
 public:
  typedef KdPoint<real, dimensions> KdPointType;
  // stuff
};
```

This can then be accessed like this:

```
KdTree<float, 5>::KdPointType
```

Comment: Thank you - the first option is the most practical in my case.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename real, size_t dimensions> class KdTree
{
    public:
    typedef KdPoint<real, dimensions> point_type;
}
```